# How to disable animation in sap.m.ProgressIndicator on "percentValue" change?

Tags: sapui5

As the title says, how to make the `sap.m.ProgressIndicator` **not animated** when changing the percent value of it?

I cannot find a method for it, and extending would probably be the way to go, but maybe somebody has already figured it out and done it? 
My Google search was not successful though.

Comment: For readers with UI5 1.73 and above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61617503/5846045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interesting question, below is the sap.m.ProgressIndication.prototype.setPercentValue function, you can see when the percent value changes the bars values is changed via an linear animation

My suggestion, the easiest way to change this behavior is to extend the control to your own control and to redefine the setPercentValue, either remove the animate function on the bar or set time to null so there is no animation

```
sap.m.ProgressIndicator.prototype.setPercentValue = function(fPercentValue) {

var that = this;
 ...
if (that.getPercentValue() != fPercentValue) {
    // animation without rerendering
    this.$().addClass("sapMPIAnimate");
    var time = Math.abs(that.getPercentValue() - fPercentValue) * 20;
    this.setProperty("percentValue", fPercentValue, true);
    var $Bar = this.$("bar");
    $Bar.animate({
        width : fPercentValue + "%"
    }, time, "linear", function() {
        that._setText.apply(that);
        that.$().removeClass("sapMPIAnimate");
    });
}
```

something like

```
jQuery.sap.declare("my.ProgressIndicator");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.ProgressIndicator");
sap.m.ProgressIndicator.extend("my.ProgressIndicator", {
   renderer: {} 
});

my.ProgressIndicator.prototype.setPercentValue = function(fPercentValue) {

  var that = this;

// validation of fPercentValue
if (typeof (fPercentValue) == "number") {
    if (that.getPercentValue() != fPercentValue) {
        // animation without rerendering
        this.$().addClass("sapMPIAnimate");
        //var time = Math.abs(that.getPercentValue() - fPercentValue) * 20;
        var time = 0;
        this.setProperty("percentValue", fPercentValue, true);
        var $Bar = this.$("bar");
        $Bar.animate({
            width : fPercentValue + "%"
        }, time, "linear", function() {
            that._setText.apply(that);
            that.$().removeClass("sapMPIAnimate");
        });
    }

    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no convenient method to suppress this behavior.

You can only extend the control and overwrite the method setPercentValue to you desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As of UI5 1.73, the animation on `percantageValue`-change can be turned off by setting the property [`displayAnimation`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.ProgressIndicator#methods/setDisplayAnimation) to `false`.

> Determines whether a percentage change is displayed with animation.
>   Since: 1.73.

```xml
<ProgressIndicator displayAnimation="false" />
```